# Using variables to update database table

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to update the user info based on a populated dropdown. I am able to access the primary key and echo it out (id) but i cant seem to get the information to update.

Here's my function;

```
function updateTable() {

if (isset($_POST['submit'] )) {
    global $db;
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $id = $_POST['users'];

    $query = "UPDATE customers SET ";
    $query.= "first_name = '$first_name', ";
    $query.= "last_name = '$last_name' ";
    $query.= "address = '$address', ";
    $query.= "city = '$city' ";
    $query.= "state = '$state', ";
    $query.= "phone = '$phone' ";
    $query.= "email = '$email', ";
    $query.= "category = '$category' ";
    $query.= "WHERE id = $id ";
    echo $id;


    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
Try
{
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();
}
Catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include('database_error.php');
    exit();
}
$statement->closeCursor();

}
}
```

Comment: Check if your query succeeds - it'll return a boolean false if it doesn't. In that case, you can use the error handling to see what went wrong - log or print out the error. In this case, there's a typo in your query, with a missing comma after `'$last_name'`.

Comment: On a more general note - this is *not* how you should be generating your SQL. This introduces a huge injection vulnerability into your code. The database library you're using will let you use a prepared statement, and bound paraments. _Use them_.

Comment: also on `"phone = '$phone' "` and `"city = '$city' "` and category also missing comma

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents that city is missing a comma as well. ;)  And I second @andrewsi's comment; you should be using parameterized queries. That query is going to explode (without malice) the first time you get an `O'Reilly`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of syntax errors in your SQL, but nevertheless you should be using a prepared statement to bind your variables to the SQL query.

Not sure if you're using MySQLi or PDO here. For MySQLi try something like this;

```
$query = "UPDATE customers SET
     first_name = ?, 
     last_name = ?,
     address = ?,
     city = ?,
     state = ?,
     phone = ?,
     email = ?,
     category = ?
   WHERE id = ?";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('ssssssssi',$first_name,$last_name,$address,$city,$state,$phone,$email,$category,$id);
$statement->execute();
```

or for PDO try this;

```
$query = "UPDATE customers SET
     first_name = :firstname, 
     last_name = :lastname,
     address = :address,
     city = :city,
     state = :state,
     phone = :phone,
     email = :email,
     category = :category
   WHERE id = :id";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(':firstname',$first_name);
$statement->bindParam(':lastname',$last_name);
$statement->bindParam(':address',$address);
$statement->bindParam(':city',$city);
$statement->bindParam(':state',$state);
$statement->bindParam(':phone',$phone);
$statement->bindParam(':email',$email);
$statement->bindParam(':category',$category);
$statement->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

As this is an update query, there are no results to fetch. So the `fetchAll()` is not useful.

Comment: might be using pdo interface though :)